# How to export a jasper report in pdf generating tool tip's on anchor's?

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, itext

In jasper report I'm using **anchor's** with `hyperlinkTooltipExpression`

Example code:

```
 <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
            <reportElement x="267" y="94" width="100" height="30" uuid="8fa9ce3d-015c-4d13-a677-3b9dbea4c222"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Anchor Target"]]></textFieldExpression>
            <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["expert"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            <hyperlinkTooltipExpression><![CDATA["expert"]]></hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
        </textField>
```

This works in IDE preview, but if exporting to **PDF** the tooltip's are not displayed in Adobe Reader, in Document viewer (linux) they are displayed but with es. *"Go To Page x"*

Comment: The Document Viewer is an another application used in Linux environment to view PDFs file.

Comment: Does the Document Viewer display the textFieldExpression or the hyperlinkAnchorExpression?? (it can't be displaying the hyperlinkTooltipExpression)

Comment: In Document Viewer it shows  "Go To Page x".

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jasper report I can not find any support for generating tooltip's on hyper links, [JasperReport source code](http://sourceforge.net/p/jasperreports/code/ci/master/tree/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporter.java#l1929).

However you can override the `setHyperlinkInfo` on the `JRPdfExporter` generating the annotation manually.

Example on how to generate tooltip on `LocalAnchor`:

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter() {
    @Override
    protected void setHyperlinkInfo(Chunk chunk, JRPrintHyperlink link) {
        if (link!=null && link.getHyperlinkTooltip() != null && HyperlinkTypeEnum.LOCAL_ANCHOR.equals(link.getHyperlinkTypeValue())) {
            PdfFormField pushButton = PdfFormField.createPushButton(pdfWriter);
            pushButton.setFieldName(String.format("tt%s", chunk.hashCode()));//Need's unique name if multiple
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            pushButton.setWidget(rect, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE);
            pushButton.put(PdfName.TU, new PdfString(link.getHyperlinkTooltip(), PdfObject.TEXT_UNICODE));
            chunk.setAnnotation(pushButton);
            if (link.getHyperlinkAnchor() != null){                         
               pushButton.setAction(PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(link.getHyperlinkAnchor(), false));
            }
            return;         
        }
        super.setHyperlinkInfo(chunk, link);
    }
};
```

To generate tooltip on other type of `hyperlinkType` (Reference, Remote ecc), continue the implementation in similar matter.

Comment: Sorry for late reponse. Yes, this code generate the tool tip on PDFs. But I have some issue also, the tool tip  work properly, but now hyperlink is created outside the graph. I tried to change the parameter of Rectangle on Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0); but its not reflect on chart.

Comment: The best I think is to create a new question with the iText code and an image of your graph, image of your desired result..,   I only tested the code on text strings (the Rectangle says that it starts on 0,0,0,0 in the annotation relative to the chunk...